# TweenMax animation is not working for multiple pages with common java script file

Tags: html, animation, gsap

For Instance,

**Home page**

```
<div id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3">Box 3</div>
```

**inner page**

```
<!--<div id="box1">Box 1</div> -->
<div id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3">Box 3</div>
```

**JS: (Common Javascript for home page and inner page.)**

```
new TimelineMax({repeat:0}).to($('#box1'), 0.3, {css:{top:0, alpha:1,rotation:360}})
new TimelineMax({repeat:0}).to($('#box2'), 0.3, {css:{top:0, alpha:1,rotation:360}})
new TimelineMax({repeat:0}).to($('#box3'), 0.3, {css:{top:0, alpha:1,rotation:360}})
```

In Home page above code works fine..But for inner pages.. If i delete/comment #box1 the other #box2 and #box3 animation is not working. How can I ignore #box1 animation and continue with another animations.

Comment: Are the animations sequential? If so you could conditionally add the tween on box1 according to whether it exists or not. if ($('#box1').length) { new TimelineMax() }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce that issue. Are you using the latest version of the GreenSock files? Could you post a codepen or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Also, you could greatly simplify your code:

```
TweenLite.to("#box1, #box2, #box3", 0.3, {top:0, alpha:1, rotation:360});
```

Your code wasn't "wrong" - just verbose. And if you're not doing sequencing, you don't really need to use TimelineMax (although it's perfectly fine if you prefer that workflow). If you meant to sequence those animations, though, you could do that easily using TimelineMax's staggerTo() method like this:

```
new TimelineMax().staggerTo(["#box1", "#box2", "#box3"], 0.3, {top:0, alpha:1, rotation:360}, 0.3);
```

Use that last parameter to control the stagger/spacing.

Again, make sure you've got the [latest version](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/?download=GSAP-JS) and that you're loading CSSPlugin and TweenLite on that inner page.

Comment: Thanks Jack.. 

Your suggestions work for me. I update latest version and make changes in my code as per your suggestion. Its working now. Being design GreenSock is new for me. Will keep in touch with you - incase need any help in future :)

Thanks for solution :)